# Android: LayoutInflater and findViewById woes

Tags: android, android-inflate

I'm trying to use LayoutInflater in a loop, but each time one of these guys is instantiated, I need to modify at least 2 TextViews found within each instantiation. What i currently have at the moment instantates appropriately and adds the inflated xml view just like I want it to, but the result is that only the first instatiaton's resources are getting modified, and therefore it just gets overwritten many times.

```
            LayoutInflater inflater;
            TextView eTitle;

            for(String[] episode : episodes) {

                //Log.d("Episodes", episode[0] + " / " + episode[2]);
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.episode_list_item, listView);
                eTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.episode_list_item_title);

                eTitle.setText(episode[2]);
            }
```

Example output of my list:

- 04 - Episode 04
- Episode Title
- Episode Title
- Episode Title

where its supposed to look like this:

- 01 - Episode 01
- 02 - Episode 02
- 03 - Episode 03
- 04 - Episode 04

what do i need to do to ensure that im getting the corresponding unique textview id's from my inflated layouts?

Comment: The code you have posted look pretty nasty. Can you explain in which place are you writing this(i.e which class, and which method)?

Comment: uh.. nothing special, this is in my episodes class, it does an asynch call to my server to collect json, it then parses the json and places the controlled set of elements into an ArrayList<String[]> known as "episodes", and this all takes place in the onCreate.

Here i'm for'ing through the episodes in the array list. None of the other stuff is relevant though, im pulling the correct data, the only issue is this layoutinflater and the findViewById not grabbing the correct resource in my instantiated views.

Comment: I could explain though that the "listView" element that I'm using the layout inflater on, is just a vertical oriented LinearLayout lol

Comment: is this a `listView`? or just have some static `TextView`s ?

Comment: "listView" is just a name in this context and a coincidence that there is something called a ListView. listView in this case is just a vertical orientated LinearLayout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you use ListView instead?

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

for(String[] episode : episodes) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.episode_list_item, null);
    mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.episode_list_item_title);
    mTitle.setText(episode[2]);

listView.addView(view);

}
```

Comment: this solution ended up working PERFECTLY. Though i didn't use a ListView, I just used my existing listView object which is just a LinearLayout object, but it still ended up working perfectly. See what I didn't know, and what was the magic trick, is the View view = inflater etc. I didn't know i could assign a view object like that, and it makes total sense now, becuase using view means im referencing the particular isntance. Beautiful! Thanks :D!

Comment: That worked for me... it seems I used almost exactly the same code that I had, but in a different order (My layout inflater and listview I moved outside of the loop, and I set the text before adding it to the listVie)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a few `TextView`s in your `LinearLayout`. One point is they can't have the same `id`s. So suppose you have 4 `TextView` , then give each different `id`s, say `tv1`, `tv2` etc.

Now in your `onCreate` method, initialize all these textViews as:

> `myTextView1= (TextView)findViewByid(R.id.tv1);`

etc etc...

In the function where you get the "episodes" try this:

> `myTextView1.setText(episodes[0]);
>
> myTextView2.setText(episodes[1]);

You don't have to use any `inflater` because its already there in the activities `layout` file, which is automatically done in `onCreate`.

Comment: +1. A good thought, but I think, it is only the half of the solution ;-). And sorry, I think that setting of IDs dynamically is good, but looking for them is excessive. We have just *made* them. So, we have them, why that searching?

Answer (score 0):

Change the lines

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.episode_list_item, listView);
eTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.episode_list_item_title);
```

into  lines:

```
eTitle =inflater.inflate(R.layout.episode_list_item, listView, false);
listView.addChild(eTitle );
```

The one-line construct of `View eTitle =inflater.inflate(R.layout.episode_list_item, listView, true);` simply never really works in practice.

And aqs is right (the second time a day I am making a compliment to him), create id's dynamically, your xml layouts for eTitle should be free of id if you wait for many of them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're forgetting to capture the view that's being inflated and then looking WITHIN that view for the new control.

Here's your original code:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.episode_list_item, listView);
eTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.episode_list_item_title);
```

I think Your code should look more like this (finding the view contained by the inflated view):

```
View new_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.episode_list_item, listView, false);
eTitle = (TextView) new_view.findViewById(R.id.episode_list_item_title);
eTitle.setText(episode[2]);
listView.addView(new_view);
```

This is what got my code working as expected.

Hope that helps!

John